# Java versioning (beta)

Tags: java

When I type java -version this is output I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

Now I'm wondering, what does -b07 mean? I assume it is a beta version mark (according to other sources: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning ), but I cannot find the Sun/Oracle reference that says so.

Does anyone know where to find complete reference of Java version naming?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/versioning-naming-139433.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the build number. From [Oracle's documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u17-141447.html):

> The full internal version number for this update release is
>   1.6.0_17-b04 (where "b" means "build").

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a 'beta' mark. It'S the internal build of this version. Nothing for you (or me) to worry about.